# PickerView data not proper on using multiple pickerview

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am using multiple pickerview on one viewcontroller. I am getting correct data in the respective pickerviews but the view of rows symmetry in the pickerview is not correct. The data view in 1st pickerview is correct but in the second pickerview the rows start from the bottom of the pickerview.

I have attached screenshots of both pickerviews.

[1st pickerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reLqR.jpg)

[2nd pickerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxG0N.jpg)

For distinguishing between the 2 pickers, I have used pickerview tags.

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if pickerView.tag == 31{
    return arr_statename.count
    }else{
        return arr_cityname.count
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if pickerView.tag == 31{
        return arr_statename[row]
    }else{
        return arr_cityname[row]
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if pickerView.tag == 31{
        state.text = arr_statename[row]
    }else{
        city.text = arr_cityname[row]
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the data in second pickerView count before and after setting the state name using first picker view?

Comment: Yes. I have checked the data count in second pickerView. Its the same.

Comment: add ViewDidLoad in ViewWillAppear code .

Comment: @KKRocks how would that help on adding on ViewWillAppear?

Comment: my mistake please mention that method here .

Comment: @KKRocks which method?

Comment: your viewWillApprar and ViewDidLoad method mention here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope might be helpful!!

Just add the observer in view did load

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.updatePicker), name: UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification, object: nil)
```

and Reload the components

```
func updatePicker(){
    self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
}
```

Comment: I haven't integrated it as an input for textfield. I have placed a button over the textfield which call the method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a single pickerView with 2 components instead of two separate pickerViews on the same viewController?  If it fulfills the needs of your app, using a single multi-component pickerView provides a better UI and avoids the types of problems you are experiencing.